# In compose, why modify the properties of the List element, LazyColumn does not refresh

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, compose-recomposition

When I modify the properties of the objects in the List, the UI does not update

my code：

```kotlin
    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun ContactCard(
    ) {
        var stateList = remember {
            mutableStateListOf<ListViewData>()
        }
        viewModel!!.recordRespListLiveData!!.observe(this) { it ->
            it.forEach {
                stateList.add(ListViewData(false, it))
            }
        }
        LazyColumn() {
            stateList.forEachIndexed { index, bean ->
                stickyHeader() {
                    Box(Modifier.clickable {
                        stateList[index].visible = true
                    }) {
                        ContactNameCard(bean.data.contact, index)
                    }
                }
                items(bean.data.records) { data ->
                    if (bean.visible) {
                        RecordItemCard(record = data)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I click on the Box, visible is set to true, but the RecordItemCard doesn't show，why？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For SnapshotList to trigger you need to add, delete or update existing item with new instance. Currently you are updating visible property of existing item.

If `ListViewData` is instance from data class you can do it as

```
stateList[index] = stateList[index].copy(visible = true)
```